# VNC viewer failing to make connection with "channel 3: open failed: connect failed: No route to host"

Tags: bash, ssh, vnc, vnc-viewer

I ssh into a server with the following:

```
ssh -g -L5912:server:5912 user@host
```

It goes through, and I can access my files on the other server through the command line (meaning I can connect to the server, it is my vnc viewer that is failing!) but when I try to open my vnc viewer (RealVNC) and connect to localhost:12 i get the following error message in the vnc viewer application:

> The connection closed unexpectedly.

Additionally in the original command line shell i get:

```
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: No route to host
```

I've tried switching to different ports and even checked out other posts on the same error message but the problem is i don't really understand them... ssh tunnels are still relatively new to me so i don't really know what im doing. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I should also mention that last week I used the exact same commands and it worked... So no idea why it is failing now

Comment: please check if your vnc server is actually running at that port

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to setup a port forwarding, this may fail because of many reasons:

- **SSH port forwarding** not enabled in the `host`

Check SSH server in the `host` if AllowTcpForwarding is enabled:

```
$ grep AllowTcpForwarding /etc/ssh/sshd_config
AllowTcpForwarding yes
```

Typically, it's commented out. Uncomment and restart the sshd.

- **No connection** between the `host` and `server` over port 5912

SSH to the `host` and try:

```
$ telnet server 5912
Connected to server.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

- Finally, **does the `server` listen** on 5912?

Similarly, as above, but from the `server` - go there and try `telnet server 5912`.

Best regards,
Jarek

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was the **port forwarding rule** I had set in **Putty**.

Please make sure you enter the correct hostname when defining the rule in Putty. I changed

> localhost:5903

with

> myserver:5903

and it worked...